# How to upsert_all/insert_all with Mobility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobility

I need to save a large number of `posts` with a translated `body` attribute, so I'm trying to use [`insert_all`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/insert_all)/[`upsert_all`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/upsert_all) in conjunction with [Mobility](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility). Saving posts individually works just fine:

```rb
Post.create({
  body_en: "Hello world",
  body_ja: "ハロー・ワールド",
  ...
})
```

However, trying to use `insert_all` results in an error since `body` is not stored in the posts table, but rather in mobility_text_translations table related via a polymorphic association (I'm using the default key/value backend):

```rb
posts = []

# In a loop, add many posts to the posts array
post = {
  body_en: "Hello world",
  body_ja: "ハロー・ワールド".
  ...
}

posts << post

# Add posts to DB at some interval
Post.insert_all(posts)
# => unknown attribute 'body_en' for Post. (ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError)
```

I think this is somewhat similar to [ActionText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61059490/rails-how-to-use-bulk-import-with-action-text), where instead of `ActionText::RichText.insert_all(post_bodies)` I wonder if we could do something like `Mobility::TextTranslations.insert_all(post_bodies)`. However, I don't see this capability discussed on the GitHub page nor in the issues.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is because Mobility handles a single entry when you call create, as follows -

1. The before_save callback fires;
2. If the model does not have an attribute, for example `body_fr`, then it is removed from the list for the entry, and instead an entry is created in the Mobility table for the `body` attribute and the `fr` locale with a link to the main entry in the `posts` table.

Performing bulk operations in ActiveRecord does not trigger this callback.
So, if you want to improve speed of inserting or updating many records, you can wrap iteration about data inside transaction.

```rb
data = [{body_en: 'aaa', body_fr: 'aaa'}, {body_en: 'bbb', body_fr: 'bbb'}]
::ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  data.each do |post|
    Post.create(post)
  end
end
```